# Why are my C# enums not working?

Tags: c#, casting, enums

I am having trouble with enums in C#

I have an enum here:

```
namespace Project.Shared
{
    public enum CostType
    {
        Dollars,
        Percent
    }
}
```

I have an object that is trying to use the enum here:

```
using Project.Shared;
namespace Project.Shared.FooNamespace
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public int CostType { get; set; }

        public Foo()
        {

            CostType = (int)CostType.Dollars; // <--- error syntax highlighting on 'Dollars'
        }
    }
}
```

This results in an error:

> 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Dollars' and no extension method 'Dollars' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I do not understand why I can't use my enum there. Can someone help explain it to me?

Comment: This may be a hint that you shouldn't use the same name for the enum as for the property.

Comment: Why do you want to store the value as an int if you've got the enum and you want the enum value?

Comment: Because EntityFramework does not support mapping to Enums yet.

Comment: @JohnSaunders As far as I know, this behavior isn't generally considered bad style. It's also a common pattern in the BCL.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: 10,000 wrongs don't make a right.

Comment: @John I'd argue to original wrong lies with the C# language design for allowing this ambiguity. If I had designed C#, every member access on the current instance would have to be prefixed with a `.`. e.g. `.CostType`. This also resolves ambiguities between parameters and private fields.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: OK, so how would you disambiguate a namespace and a type that have the same name?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because your class `Foo` has this definition - `public int CostType { get; set; }` - which has more local scope than your `enum`.

Try fully qualifying it with its namespace:

```
CostType = (int)Project.Shared.CostType.Dollars;
```

Comment: Additionally, I would do `this.CostType =` to help with the ambiguity of `CostType`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips +1 I'm with ya. Lots of folks seem to *despise* seeing the `this` qualifier in code though...

Comment: Whats about int.parse(CostType.toString("d")) compared to (int)CostType; ?

Answer (score 12):

As others have pointed out, the property is "closer" than the type, and so when the simple name is resolved, the property always wins.

An interesting wrinkle on this situation though is that *if you had made the property of type CostType rather than int, it would have worked.*

The reason for that is because C# has a special rule just for that situation, usually called the "Color Color" rule. (Because that is the situation in which it most commonly arises: a type named Color and a property called Color of type Color.)

If a simple name could mean both a type *and* a property or field *with that name, of that type*, then C# allows you to both access static members via the type *and* instance members via the property. This allows you to do things like:

```
Color = Color.Red;
description = Color.ToString();
```

The first and third Colors are references to the property; the second is a reference to the type.

Answer (score 1):

You have naming conflict. You named you property `CostType` which is the same as enum name. This way C# is assuming that both `CostType` references in `Foo()` method are referencing the property and not enum.

You could try this:

```
CostType = (int)Project.Shared.CostType.Dollars;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in `CostType = (int)CostType.Dollars;` Both occurances of `CostType` refer to the variable. And the variable `CostType` has no property called `Dollars`. Include the namespace to refer to the type `Project.Shared.CostType` to explicitly refer to the type, not the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this and it should work

```
public enum CostType
{ 
    Dollars,
    Percent 
} 

public class Foo
{         
    public int CostTypes { get; set; }
    public Foo()
    { 
        CostTypes = (int)CostType.Dollars;
        // <--- error syntax highlighting on 'Dollars'
    }
}
```

I would not name my auto property the same name as my enum CostType I tested this and what I have posted did compile and work

Comment: naming this property `CostTypes` makes no sense. It's not a flags enum, and thus can only represent a single `CostType`. So why are you using the plural?

Comment: I looked as his question as having an access issue or compile issue if that's the case then he should have namespaces either fully qualified of have them match

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - Per Yuck's answer I am now fully qualifying the names

Comment: I see that.. but based on your initial error I took that to be a naming issue.. my mistake.. that's why I pluralized my example sorry

Comment: +1 because your answer does solve my issue... I would just rather not have the plural naming.

Comment: That's fine I appreciate that I tried your code in my project got the same error so I was only trying to lend a helping hand in regards to solving the compiler error.. remember guys Many ways to skin a cat LOL

Answer (score 0):

I solved my: 'ENUM does not contain a definition for VALUE' error, by restarting Visual Studio. Just in case anyone has the same problem.